# Feel the need to improve my RegExp's

Tags: c++, regex

I'm working with a HTTP library (winhttp) for 2 weeks now and now I want to improve my RegExp's for retrieving some data on the target website.

Given the following HTML code:

```
Total Posts:</span> 22,423</li>
```

Now what I want to do is retrieving only the number and storing it into a variable:

```
regex = "Total Posts:</span> \\S+"; 

if(std::regex_search(regexs, regexmatch, regex))
{
    temp = regexmatch[0];
    found = temp.find(",");
    if(found != std::string::npos)
        temp.erase(found, 1);
    temp.erase(0, 19);
    temp.erase(temp.end() - 5, temp.end());
    User._Posts = ConvertStringToInteger(temp);
}
```

Used some RegExp for this and stripping the parts off since I don't get how I only retrieve the pattern, not the whole result. Hopefully someone understands me. Already looked up the docs but found nothing what could help me.

Comment: This may be relevant:  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Yes, it is maybe better not to use RegEx for this task. RegEx is hardly ever performant and there are plenty of (X)HTML parser arround, which parse text fast forward on a pointer basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only match your desired pattern, you're wanting to use a capture group with [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

Capture groups are meant for capturing matched regions within a regular expression and each captured region is represented by a `sub_match`. You can use the `smatch` specialization of `match_results` for working with string sub matches and then use the operator `[]` to get the match.

Example:

```
const std::string foo = "Total Posts:</span> 22,423</li>";

std::regex rgx("Total Posts:</span> ([^<]+)");
std::smatch match;

if (std::regex_search(foo.begin(), foo.end(), match, rgx)) {
    std::cout << match[1] << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
22,423
```